# How to get the pixel data of a bmp image in c

Tags: c, bmp

How do you get the pixel data of a bmp image in C?

I can read the structure of the image but is there a way to display the pixel data?

Comment: What do you mean by "display"?

Comment: As the name says: It's a bitmap, pixels come on after another, bit by bit.

Comment: @alk - true, but they start after some offset, as this file format has some specific headers.

Comment: Bitmaps usually have a structure associated with them - that's called the header of the image. What follows the image header is the actual image data. That data is in RGB format(IIRC). You will have to unpack the data and "display" accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I need to access the pixels of the image. From googling, i got the header information and the offset. So how can i get the pixels.

Comment: You are right, absolutly. Details here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Bitmap_file_header @KirilKirov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the easiest way of doing it in C, and not C++ is using [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/). This library contains a C API that will make your life easier. You can see more details on the documentation, but your code to do a simple task like that would looks like this piece of code:

```
IplImage* img = 0; 
uchar *data;

// load an image  
img=cvLoadImage("filename.bmp");
if(!img)
{
   printf("Could not load image file: %s\n",argv[1]);
   exit(0);
}

// create a window
cvNamedWindow("mainWin", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); 
cvMoveWindow("mainWin", 100, 100);

// show the image
while(1)
{
   cvShowImage("mainWin", img );
   if(cvWaitKey(30) > 0)
   break;
}

// release the image
cvReleaseImage(&img);
```

Comment: How about Imagemagick?.. I have tried  MagickWand and MagickCore, the MagickGetImagePixels() extracts pixel data from an image, but gives me an error the method deprecated.. Ok i will try using OpenCV..

Comment: Never used any of those, but I have plenty of experience with OpenCV. It's easy, clean and have a large community to support you.